# Auto check Allow external users to sign up in General settings page

Tags: xml, odoo, updates, odoo-8

I need to check **Allow external users to sign up ** field in general settings during installation of my custom module. i tried below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <openerp>
       <data>
            <record id="auto_check_auth_signup_uninvited" model="base.config.settings">
                    <field name="auth_signup_uninvited"> True</field>
                    <field name="auth_signup_reset_password">True</field>
            </record>
      </data>
    </openerp>
```

**And**

```
   <record id="auto_check_auth_signup_uninvited" model="base.config.settings">
        <field name="auth_signup_uninvited" eval="True"/>
        <field name="auth_signup_reset_password" eval="True"/>
   </record>
```

Both of code didn't work. How can i do it?

[image]

I need check these two Boolean field pro-grammatically.

Comment: What exactly `didn't work` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got answer:

```
<function model="ir.config_parameter" name="set_param" eval="('auth_signup.allow_uninvited', True)" />
<function model="ir.config_parameter" name="set_param" eval="('auth_signup.reset_password', True)" />
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issues using the scripts above. You could use sql and a migration script. Create a migrations directory in your addon. Then create a directory named the same version of your addon. So if you addon is version 8.0.0.1.1 then your directory would also be called "8.0.0.1.1". Make sure the version in **openerp**.py and this directory are the same.

/addon_name/migrations/addon_version/post-migrate.py

Then create a post_migration.py that looks like this.

```
def migrate(cr, version):
    sql = "UPDATE ir_config_parameter SET value='True' WHERE key='auth_signup.allow_uninvited' OR key='auth_signup.reset_password'"
    cr.execute(sql)
```

Then update (or install) your addon.

Comment: I used the logic from your answer

Comment: Great, I am not familiar with the function tag in xml data files. I will try your approach as it looks much better than a migration script.